# How to display unicode characters in ncmpcpp

Tags: terminal, unicode, mpd

I am using Arch Linux and have UTF-8 encoding enabled. But how can I display a unicode character in ncmpcpp via the config file of ncmpcpp?

I already added the line `filesystem_charset "UTF-8"` to `/etc/mpd.conf`, which I think is unnecessary.

In the `~/.ncmpcpp/config` file, I tried `progressbar_look = "\u25BA"` but it spits out all the characters as they are. Also tried setting

```
system_encoding = "utf8"
```

in `~/.ncmpcpp/config` but doesn't seem to work. BTW, I can print unicode on the terminal. I'm using `xfce4-terminal` if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can just enter ► directly in the config file, without any escaping. Note that the `progressbar_look` setting must contain exactly two or three characters.